# How to prove $\sqrt{3}$ is a irrational number using direct proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, solution-verification, computational-mathematics

I can prove this easily using proof of contradiction method but I am stuck at proving this using direct proof

Comment: What should a direct proof of a negative statement ("$\sqrt 3$ is **not** of the form $\frac ab$ with integers $a,b$") look like?

Comment: I suppose you could prove that $\sqrt{3}$ has a non-terminating continued fraction $[1; 1,2,1,2,1,2,\ldots]$ and therefore is irrational.

Comment: I agree that one should always prefer direct proofs to contradiction proofs, but... this is maybe the exception that proves the rule.

Comment: We have very little machinery to handle irrational numbers, but two and a half millennia worth of machinery to handle rational numbers. It's a **lot** easier to prove that $\sqrt3$ breaks the rational machinery than proving that it works in the irrational machinery.

Comment: If one uses the usual logic (and not strange logics without "exluding of the middle" , for example), nothing speaks against a contradiction proof, unless we have a direct proof with the same or less effort. If a direct proof is easy enough, I would nevertheless prefer a direct proof as well. Irrationality proofs however are in general extremely difficult and we can be glad to have a proof at all.

Comment: You might find this post interesting: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32011/direct-proof-of-irrationality

Comment: Hmmm https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32011/direct-proof-of-irrationality  The accepted answer seems to me to fail to be direct.  It's *still* claiming If the square root of 2 were rational it'd be an integer.  It's not an integer so it is not rational.  I'm not going to say proving something is *not* something directly is impossible but.... well, yes, I am but I'll listen to anyone who can tell me why I am wrong if I am.

Comment: @fleablood Yes that seems to be the consensus on the accepted answer there. Perhaps I should have clarified that the OP might find that post interesting since it speaks to the inherent difficulty/impossibility of their question. There are some interesting blog posts linked there too.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt3$ is a root of $X^2-3$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (Eisenstein)

Comment: And how is Eisenstein proven? Usually by assuming there is a factorisation of the polynomial, and then showing that the coefficients don't work out. This doesn't get rid of the indirectness of the proof, just hides it a bit.

Comment: according to me this argument is direct, you can eventually go back, to construction of sets, Grothendieck universes,..., or to the definition of a theory in math (Bourbaki), you always start with axioms, which are kinda indirect assertions.

Comment: by the way who told you there does not exist a direct proof of the Eisenstein criterion ?

Comment: Since you are the one making the claim that this approach leads to a direct proof, I think the burden of evidence is on you to demonstrate that this is indeed the case. I have only seen the standard contradiction proof of Eisenstein, so to my knowledge, Eisenstein is proven indirectly. And then you would need to do the same to any theorems you use in the proof of Eisenstein. All in all, showing that some well-known relatively advanced result can be shown directly is a _lot_ of work, because there are so many details to check.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can use the fact that if $f(x)$ is a monic polynomial with integer coefficients, then any rational root of $f(x)$ is necessarily an integer. Now, applying this to the polynomial $f(x) = x^{2} − 3$ you can conclude that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational number.

Comment: Isn't this still a proof by contradiction?  It follows the form: Any rational root would have a charactaristic.  That characteristic fails.  So it is an irrational root.